# Statsmodels SARIMAX reproducible forecasts

Tags: forecasting, statsmodels

I am using Statsmodels SARIMAX to make forward-looking forecasts and I want to be able to reproduce my forecasts at a later time. Is there any way to ensure that forecasts will be the same between different runs and is there any functionality for setting a random seed?

Comment: SARIMAX should be deterministic, so you should get the exact same model and forecast if you re-run it with the same training data. Are you seeing differences on the same training data? Or are you actually asking about getting the same forecast if you refit your model using different data? If so, please clarify.

Comment: The data hasn't changed and neither have the hyperparameters (order and sorder). Is there some random state with Sarimax.fit that could give different coefficients?

Comment: That should absolutely not happen. Can you please edit your question and include a minimal (!) reproducible example?